# How to apply Styled Component styles to a custom React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a Styled Component called `StyledButton` and a React component called `AddToCart`. I want to apply the styled from `StyledButton` to `AddToCart`.

I have already tried the following:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
import AddToCart from "./AddToCart";
import StyledButton from "./styles/StyledButton";

const StyledAddToCart = styled(AddToCart)`
  ${StyledButton}
`;
```

What I want to do is already in the documentation at https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components but this applies new styles to the component. The problem is that I want to use existing styled from a Styled Component (`StyledButton`)

From the documentation:

```js
// This could be react-router-dom's Link for example
const Link = ({ className, children }) => (
  <a className={className}>
    {children}
  </a>
);

const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-weight: bold;
`;

render(
  <div>
    <Link>Unstyled, boring Link</Link>
    <br />
    <StyledLink>Styled, exciting Link</StyledLink>
  </div>
);
```

I would really like to have the styles from `StyledButton` applied to `StyledAddToCart` without copying the styles manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share styling with the `css` util:

```js
// import styled, {css} from 'styled-components'
const {css} = styled;

const Link = (props) => <a {...props} />

const sharedBtnStyle = css`
  color: green;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
`;

const StyledButton = styled.button`
  ${sharedBtnStyle}
`;

const AddToCartBtn = styled(Link)`
  ${sharedBtnStyle}
  color: red;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledButton>styled button</StyledButton>
      <div />
      <AddToCartBtn>styled link</AddToCartBtn>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: This solved my problem and is a nice way to share styles between components, thanks! I used `css` to extract the styled from my original component and then passed them to the original component with a template literal like you suggested.